# iOS icons: Size vs points?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

We know nothing about icons - the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) for iOS icons refer to required icons based on size (ie: 180*180) whereas the xCode Asset Catalog quotes in terms of points (ie: 29pt).  How does the size relate to points?

Also what does the "@3X" mean in the Apple docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting pixels to points depends on the target iOS device. On a 1x device (iPad 1 & 2, iPhone up to 3GS), 1 UIKit point == 1 pixel. On Retina devices (iPad 3 and up, iPhone 4 and up), 1 UIKit point == 2 pixels.

So for a instance if u are on iphone 4 and above your 29pt = (2*29)58px.

Comment: I guess this is what the 2x, 3x means on the Apple docs?  So for iPhone 6 - 1 UIKit point = 3 pixels (3x)?